# Americast Bathtub Drain

Tags: bathroom, drain, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures

I am installing an American Standard bathtub and the instructions are stating that a brass drain/overflow assembly is required. The assembly is about $150 and I would like to avoid it if possible. Is there any reason why I couldn't just use a pvc drain assembly?[image][image]

Comment: Presumably a PVC drain assembly will not last as long. Maybe there would be stress cracking or maybe just the finish would wear off. Unlike a lavatory it is not easy to change the drain assembly of a tub. Normally you would have to open up a wall and maybe pull a toilet to get good access. You'd like to have the drain last the service life of the tub installation.

Comment: Thats quite debatable. I've seen copper and brass pipes fail from corrosion where a PVC pipe would have lasted much longer... And, of course, one could choose the "provide an access panel" approach to plumbing installation rather than the cheap developer approach of sealing it all behind drywall...